# What is the best screen resolution for an Android AVD?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

This is might seem to be a sort of silly question to ask but I would like to know while testing our apps what is the best resolution to be used (HVGA/WVGA/QVGA?etc)?

I ask this because I want the layout and the performance of the device to be consistent across most screen sizes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a regularly updated diagram with the screen sizes and densitys available at the android developers site:

[image]

[Source](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/screens.html)

This doesn't tell you an exact resolution, but seperates all phones into 4 sizes (small, normal, large, xlarge) and densities. This should give you a hint at least.

The biggest chunk is obviously Normal/hdpi, I guess that should be a lot of 3.7" HDPI displays with a 480x800 resolution (or at least close to this res). Like the Nexus One or HTC Desire (there are sure some newer ones, but I only keep an eye on the market when I'm searching for a phone to buy).

Comment: Ooh...I like this diagram..makes things so much clearer! Thank you so much...really appreciate it:)

Comment: HDPI represent WVGA resolution

Comment: Actually no. Sure most of the HDPI devices are WVGA at the moment, but not exclusively. HDPI just says this device has a high number of pixels per inch (~190-280 dpi). There are for example FWVGA devices (thats why I said "close to WVGA" above). Or look at the diagram above, there are also hdpi devices with a "small" display, i doubt these are WVGA.

Answer (score 2):

You can use all resolution to test your application, because some phones have QVGA resolution, some HVGA or WVGA resolution. Tablets have others resolutions.
More informations : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I am trying to understand which resolution is most common among Android handsets. I mean that would help me cover a larger percentage of models in the market, right?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `dp` unit for the sizes of your screen elements, then you shouldn't need to worry (as much) as this is a relative size, based on the pixel density of the screen.